# Connecting to DDE datasource

Tags: php, asp.net, .net, dde

I need to read data from a DDE stream.  I'm looking to use PHP or ASP.NET to connect to the data stream and pull back the data I need.  I have no knowledge of how to go about this, can anyone point me in the right direction to get me started?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ended up using VB 2008 to write an application that uses the [NDde](https://ndde.codeplex.com/) library.
Working correctly now.